# jqGrid field editable on inline Add but not on inline Edit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using Inline editing in my Grid. I want 'inhouseSatgeName' filed to be editable on ADD click where as not editable on EDIT click .If I set editable:false, it does not allow me to add. Below is my code and the field is a dropdown.

```
    jQuery("#gridId").jqGrid({

                            colNames : [ 'Vendor Id','Project Id','Stage Id','Stage Name', 'Planned Start Date','Planned End date', 'Internal Team','Lead Name'],
                            colModel : [ 

                            {
                                name : 'inhouseStageName',
                                index : 'inhouseStageName',

                                edittype : "select",
                                editrules : {
                                    required : true
                                },
                                editable : true,

                            }]
```