# jqGrid - disabling inline dropdown on "edit" but not on "add"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, inline-editing

It looks as if this question has been asked at least [once before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524020/jqgrid-field-editable-on-inline-add-but-not-on-inline-edit) but was not answered.  I have also seen this question answered regarding standard "form" based editing, but not inline.

**Code**

```
$(function() {
var lastSel;
var MSVendors = {'9990':'XXXXXX - LEXI','9991':'XXXXXX - RICH','9992':'XXXXXX - BIRM','9993':'XXXXXX - PEMB' };
$('#special_dialog').dialog({
    width:'auto',
    height:'auto',
    resizable:true
});
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults,{
    rowNum:250,
    rowList:[1000,2500,5000],
    viewrecords:true,
    sortorder:'asc',
    height:800,
    autowidth:true,
    deepempty:true,
    altRows: true,
    grouping: true,
    groupingView: {
        groupField: ["vendor"],
        groupColumnShow: [true],
        groupText: ["<b>WAREHOUSE : {0}</b>"],
        groupDataSorted: true,
        groupSummary: [false]
    }
});
var surplusGrid = $('#surplusGrid'),
    editingRowId,
    sEditParam = {
        keys: true,
        oneditfunc: function(id) {
            editingRowId = id;
            $('#surplusGrid_ilsave').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
            $('#surplusGrid_ilcancel').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
        },
        afterrestorefunc: function() {
            editingRowId = undefined;
        }
    },
    sAutoCompOpts = {
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON('/json/json.searchmultiMaterials.php',{term:request.term,type:'m'},function(data) {
                response(data);
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        focus: function(e,ui) {
            $('input:text[name="description"]').val(ui.item.description);
            $('input:text[name="vendor"]').val(ui.item.vendor);
            $('input:text[name="mfgr_partno"]').val(ui.item.mfgr_partno);
        },
        select: function(e,ui) {
            $('input:text[name="description"]').val(ui.item.description);
            $('input:text[name="vendor"]').val(ui.item.vendor);
            $('input:text[name="mfgr_partno"]').val(ui.item.mfgr_partno);
        }
    },
    sAddParam = {
        rowID: 'new',
        position:'last'
    };
surplusGrid.jqGrid({
    url: '/json/json.getSurplusStock.php',
    datatype:'json',
    emptyrecords: 'Surplus Stock is currently depleted!',
    colNames: ['ID','Type','Part#','Description','On-Hand','On-Order','On-Hold','Min Stock','Warehouse','Shelf','Bin'],
    colModel: [
        {   name:'id',
            index:'id',
            hidden:true,
            key:false,
            search:false,
            viewable:false
        },
        {   name:'type',
            index:'type',
            width:35,
            sortable:true,
            editable:false,
            align:'center',
            editoptions:{defaultValue:'B'},
            cellattr: function(rowId,val) {
                if (val == 'B') {
                    return 'class="blue_stock"';
                } else {
                    return 'class="gold_stock"';
                }
            }
        },
        {   name:'surplus_partno',
            index:'surplus_partno',
            width:140,
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            classes:'ui-ellipsis',
            edittype:'text',
            editoptions:{size:25},
            editrules:{required:true}
        },
        {   name:'description',
            index:'description',
            width:200,
            sortable:false,
            align:'left',
            editable:true,
            classes:'ui-ellipsis',
            edittype:'text',
            editoptions:{size:40},
            editrules:{required:true}
        },
        {   name:'on_hand',
            index:'on_hand',
            width:60,
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            align:'center',
            edittype:'text',
            editoptions:{size:6},
            editrules:{required:true,integer:true,minValue:0}
        },
        {   name:'on_order',
            index:'on_order',
            width:60,
            sortable:false,
            editable:true,
            align:'center',
            edittype:'text',
            editoptions:{size:6},
            editrules:{required:false,integer:true,minValue:0}
        },
        {   name:'on_hold',
            index:'on_hold',
            width:60,
            sortable:true,
            editable:true,
            align:'center',
            edittype:'text',
            editoptions:{size:6},
            editrules:{required:true,integer:true}
        },
        {   name:'min_threshold',
            index:'min_threshold',
            width:60,
            sortable:true,
            editable:true,
            align:'center',
            edittype:'text',
            editoptions:{size:6},
            editrules:{required:true,integer:true,minValue:0}
        },
        {   name:'vendor',
            index:'vendor',
            width:120,
            editable:true,
            align:'center',
            editoptions:{value:MSVendors},
            edittype:'select',
            editrules:{required:true,integer:true}
        },
        {   name:'shelf',
            index:'shelf',
            width:40,
            sortable:true,
            editable:true,
            align:'center',
            editoptions:{size:10}
        },
        {   name:'bin',
            index:'bin',
            width:40,
            sortable:true,
            editable:true,
            align:'center',
            editoptions:{size:10}
        }
    ],
    pager:'#surplusFoot',
    sortname:'b.id',
    caption:'Surplus Stock Inventory',
    onSelectRow: function(id) {
        if(id && id !== lastSel) {
            surplusGrid.jqGrid('restoreRow',lastSel);
            var cm = surplusGrid.jqGrid('getColProp','vendor');
            if (id != 'new') { cm.editable = false; }
            lastSel = id;
        }
        surplusGrid.jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
        $('#surplusGrid_ilsave').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
        $('#surplusGrid_ilcancel').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
    },
    editurl:'/jqg/jqg.saveSurplusStockEdit.php'
});
surplusGrid.jqGrid('navGrid','#surplusFoot',{
    add:false,
    edit:false,
    del:false
});
surplusGrid.jqGrid('inlineNav','#surplusFoot',{
    add:true,
    edit:true,
    editParams:sEditParam,
    addParams:sAddParam
});
// re-size all grids when dialog box resizes
$('#special_dialog').dialog({
    resizeStop: function(e,ui) {
        surplusGrid.jqGrid('setGridWidth', ui.size.width - 30);
    }
});
```

});

Works GREAT on inline ADD - dropdown appears and value is passed to the editing URL as expected. On inline EDIT, however, the entire dropdown vanishes, leaving a " " as the cell content rather than the value that was there when the grid initially loaded.

Comment: Sorry, but your question in unclear. You wrote about both inline editing and form editing, about ADD and EDIT. **What editing mode and how you use?** Do you use inline editing explicitly called in `onSelectRow` (call of `editRow`) or you use `formatter: "action"` or you use `inlineNav` or ... Why the code `id != 'new'` should work for you?  Even it's unclear which version of jqGrid you use? Some old one probably? Which options of `addRow` you use? Which `datatype` you use? Do you use local editing `editurl: "clientArray"` or remote editing. ... I can continue...

Comment: Yes, I use ONLY inLine editing. jqGrid v4.6.0, remote editing via an ajax call. I do not use the "formatter" option. I will edit my code to be all inclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `inlineNav` is a special case of inline editing, because `editRow` will be called. Starting with jqGrid 4.5.3 inline editing supports `beforeEditRow` and `beforeAddRow` callbacks which was introduced mostly to provide additional customization in case of usage `inlineNav`. The method `beforeEditRow` is more interesting, because it will be called in any way of calling `editRow`.

Before providing an example of usage `beforeEditRow` I would remark that you have to fix the bug in `sAddParam`, which you use as the option of `addRow`. You use unneeded and danger parameter `rowID: 'new'`. As the result the id of **every** new row will be the same: "new". In the way you will have id duplicates. The same problem exists in early versions of jqGrid. The current version of jqGrid uses  `$.jgrid.randId()` to generate new *unique* id for new added row if `rowID` is `null` or `undefined`. The default value of `rowID` is `null`. So I strictly recommend you to remove `rowID: 'new'` option.

The next important thing is the meaning of `addParams` option of `inlineNav`. The method `addRow` calls internally the same `editRow` method. The `addRowParams` property of `addParams` allows to specify the option of `editRow` called by `addRow`. So I strictly recommend you to use `addParams` in the following form

```
var sEditParam = {
        ... // any options or callbacks
    },
    sAddParam = {
        position: 'last',
        addRowParams: sEditParam
    };
```

In the way you will be sure that all callbacks and options of inline editing will be applied even in case of usage `addRow`.

Now back to you main question. I suggest that you use `beforeEditRow` to change `editable` property of `vendor` column. To test whether the current row are just add or not I suggest to test existence of `jqgrid-new-row` class. The corresponding code could be like the following

```
var sEditParam = {
    beforeEditRow: function (option, rowid) {
        var tr = $(this).jqGrid("getGridRowById", rowid);

        $(this).jqGrid("setColProp", "vendor", {
            editable: !$(tr).hasClass("jqgrid-new-row")
        });
    }
};
surplusGrid.jqGrid("inlineNav", "#surplusFoot", {
    add: true,
    edit: true,
    editParams: sEditParam,
    addParams: {position: "last", addRowParams: sEditParam}
});
```

Comment: I learn something new every time you answer a question! Thanks, Oleg