# aftersavefunc is not work in inline JqGrid properly

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am working on jqgrid.in that inline jqgrid I want to display sum of column of jqGrid into another text box outside jqgrid.I am do some code for that. the code is below

```
 $("#ItemGrid").jqGrid("inlineNav", "#nav-ItemGrid", {
        edit: true,
        add: true,
        addicon: "ui-icon-plus",
        save: true,
        view: true,
        cancel: false,
        editParams: {
            aftersavefunc: function () {
                var colSum = $('#ItemGrid').jqGrid('getCol', 'Total', false, 'sum');
                $('#TotalBeforeDiscount').val(colSum);
            },
            keys: true
        },
        addParams: {
            position: 'last',             
            aftersavefunc: function () {                  
                var colSum = $('#ItemGrid').jqGrid('getCol', 'Total', false, 'sum');
                $('#TotalBeforeDiscount').val(colSum);
            }, keys: true 
        }
    });
```

this code is work only for editParams not for AddParams.But I can not understand why this is happen.Please give some suggestion.
Thanks in advance..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `addParams` property of `inlineNav` in the wrond way. The options of inline editing like `position: 'last'` and `aftersavefunc` have to be inside of property `addRowParams` of `addParams`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27002151/315935) for example for more details. If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) then I'd recommend you to use `inlineEditing` option of jqGrid to set default properties of inline editing. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods) for more details.